# How to do i18n with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, internationalization

I'm writing a service with sprint boot. And for the persistence layer I'm using MongoDB. There's some i18n cases in my service but I'm not going to use Mongoid. Should I design the tables like other db? Or is there any best practice of doing i18n with MongoDB? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put actual values in an array inside of your document. Something like that:

```
{
"_id" : "some id",
"defaultValue" : {
    "_id" : "ENG",
    "v" : "English Value"
},
"values" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "ENG",
        "v" : "English Value"            
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "RUS",
        "v" : "Russian Value"
    }
]
```

}

When getting the value you can query with the document id plus values id to get desired language value. If desired language is not exist you can get default value.

```
db.yourDocument.find({"_id": "document id", "values._id": "ENG"}, {"values.$": 1})
```

If the query return no element check for default value:

```
db.yourDocument.find({"_id": "document id"}, {"defaultValue": 1})
```